# how to replace single column of html table onchange

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, html-table

I'm having trouble figuring out an efficient way to update a column in an html table without reloading the entire table. The table is a list of player stats, all of which are stored on my MYSQL database and loaded into the table except for the last column. The data in last column of the table comes from an XML file. There is a select drop down on the page that when the user changes it, I need the page to do some calculation on the XML data and reload only the last column of the table without having to make an AJAX call and reload the entire stats table. Currently I reload the entire table which is quite slow. This is how I am generating the table:

```
echo '<table name="currentTable" id="battersTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp </th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>AGE</th>
                        <th>
                            <select class="posSelect" onchange="posSelect(this.value, this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)">
                                <option value="ALL">POS: ALL</option>
                                <option value="C">POS: C</option>
                                <option value="1B">POS: 1B</option>
                                <option value="2B">POS: 2B</option>
                                <option value="SS">POS: SS</option>
                                <option value="3B">POS: 3B</option>
                                <option value="MI">POS: MI</option>
                                <option value="CI">POS: CI</option>
                                <option value="OF">POS: OF</option>
                            </select>
                        </th>
                        <th>TEAM</th>
                        <th>AB</th>
                        <th>R</th>
                        <th>HR</th>
                        <th>RBI</th>
                        <th>SB</th>
                        <th>AVG</th>';
                        if($draftType == 0){
                            echo '<th>ADP</th>
                        <th id="chance">CHANCE</th>';
                        }else if($draftType == 1){
                            echo '<th>$</th>';
                        }
                    echo'</tr></thead>
            <tbody id="replacebatters">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultbat, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {     
    if(array_key_exists($row['NAME'], $crossed)){
        echo "<tr class='drafted' id='" . $row['NAME'] . "'>";
    }else if(array_key_exists($row['NAME'], $rostered)){
        echo "<tr class='roster' id='" . $row['NAME'] . "'>";
    }else if($n&1){
        echo "<tr id='" . $row['NAME'] . "'>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr class='alt' id='" . $row['NAME'] . "'>";
    }

  echo '<th>Draft</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['AGE'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['POS'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TM'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['AB'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='runs'>" . $row['R'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='hr'>" . $row['HR'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='rbi'>" . $row['RBI'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='sb'>" . $row['SB'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='avg'>" . $row['AVG'] . "</td>";
if ($draftType == 0)
{
    $player = $MDCxml->xpath('//player[@name="' . $row['NAME'] . '"]');
    if (is_array($player) && count($player)) {
        $player = $player[0];
    } else {
        continue; // not found
    }

    $attr = $player->attributes(); 

    $adp = (float) $attr['adp'];
    $early = (int) $attr['early'];      

    $stdev = -0.42+0.42*($adp-$early);

    if($stdev<0)
        $stdev = 1;
    $chance =number_format(((1-NORMDIST($pickNumber,$adp,$stdev,TRUE))*100), 0);

    echo "<td class='adp'>".$adp."</td>";
    echo "<td class='odds'>".$chance."%</td>";
}elseif ($draftType == 1){
    echo "<td class='dollar'>$14</td>";
}     
  echo "</tr>";
  $n = ++$n;
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

On change of the drop down below I need to update the $pickNumber (round selected * a stored pick number) variable with the current round the user has selected and update the values in the CHANCE column with the newly calculated $chance variable. Here is the drop down select:

```
echo "Current Round: ";
    echo "<select id='round' size='1' onchange='***NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE***'>";

    for($q = 1; $q <= $rosterSizeRow['roster_size']; $q++)
    {
        if ($q == $_GET['round'])
        {
            echo "<option value=".$q." selected> ".$q." </option>";
        }else{
            echo "<option value=".$q."> ".$q." </option>";
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) for reference documentation. On the same page, the [see also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#See_also) section has several links on how to use XMLHttpRequest and how to make AJAX calls.

For a start, you can look at this untested code

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="round">Round:</label>
    <select id="round" name="round" onchange="ajaxUpdateChance(this)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" selected>3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function updateChance(data)
{
    var table = $('#battersTable');
    $('.odds', table).each(function(index, element) {
                               $(element).text(data[index] + '%');
                           });
}

function ajaxUpdateChance(el) {
    var round = el.value;
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.example.com/update_chance.php',
             data: { round: round },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: updateChance });
}
```

`ajaxUpdateChance` retrieves the data for the `odds` column. `updateChance` iterates through the `odds` column entries and sets the new text from the `data` array. The `data` array should be a JSON array.

Comment: Yes ajax is how I am currently updating the entire stats table. I guess what I am asking is what should I get as a response and how should I go about updating the only CHANCE column.

Comment: @rodzilla Do you already use jQuery? And you want to update column with `class="odds"`?

Comment: Yea I am using jQuery and that's correct I want to update the column with `class='odds'` for each player when a user changes the round dropdown.

Comment: @rodzilla This means, you need (player, odds) pairs for updating the column.

Comment: @rodzilla Please see updated answer. I assumed, the server sends just the `odds` entries as an array of text strings, encoded as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I'm not too familiar with JSON, in my update_chance.php file how should I be returning the data from the ajax call?

Comment: @rodzilla You can use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for this. If you use JSON as data type, you don't need to fiddle with parsing some HTML string or such. HTML is good, if you want to replace a complete part of your page. Although, you should use, what you're comfortable with.

Comment: @rodzilla Beware though, I haven't tested this. Most likely, you must adapt and debug, what I've written above. But I hope, it's enough for a start.